# Cross platform UTF-8 char file data encoding/decoding

Tags: c++, linux, windows, unicode, utf-8

I encode a binary file with data structures where one of the property is of wchar_t type for UTF-8 support.

Each struct looks like this:

```
 struct DataBlock{

    wchar_t charcode;
    int width;
    int height;
   ///etc

  }
```

The encoding happens on Windows where wchar_t size is 2 bytes.

The decoding of the file happens on Linux where the size is 4 bytes.So the read out values for charcode are wrong on the Linux side.

What is the best way to fix that difference without usage of [3rd party libs](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) for UTF?Is it ok to encode charcode,for example into 'int' data type on win and then on Linux cast it to wchar_t?

Comment: UTF8 is an encoding of unicode codepoints into sequences of up to 4 bytes; it has nothing to do with `wchar_t`. `wchar_t` is (supposedly) large enough to contain a codepoint, although 16 bits isn't large enough so it only works properly for the BMP. So I'm not sure what you mean by "UTF-8" support

Comment: So you mean If I make 'charcode' 4 bytes wide it will store and retrieve utf-8 char correctly on all platforms?

Comment: I mean that if you make charcode a `uint8_t[4]`, you will be able to store UTF-8 directly into it (although you'll need to deduce the length, which is easy). But that's not particularly useful as a character code, although it is convenient for building UTF-8 strings. So it depends on what you really want to do with the codes. FWIW, Unicode codepoints require 21 bits, but it's usually easier to use a `uint32_t` (or `int32_t`).

Comment: What I need is to store utf-8 chars on Windows and read them correctly on Linux into the structs as I wrote above.So from what you said I understand I can just cast to  int32_t from wchar_t and back on those platforms to get the correct representations?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "UTF-8 character". That may seem like pedantry, but it's important if you want to be clear. UTF-8 is an encoding mechanism. Now, if you're on windows and you have a wchar_t which contains the codepoint of a character in the BMP, then you can cast it to an int32_t; on Linux, `wchar_t` is a 32-bit integer, so the cast is a no-op. But if the character is not in the BMP, the situation is more complicated because on Windows the character will be encoded using a surrogate pair, so it will occupy two wchar_t's.

Comment: To put it another way, on Windows, you have the choice between utf-8 encoding (using char*) or utf-16 encoding (using wchar_t*), but there is nothing which is a simple array of unicode codepoints. On other OS, you can use utf-8 as multibyte characters (stored in char*), or arrays of unicode codepoints (stored in wchar_t*). In theory, a standard library on unix could use utf-16 as a multibyte coding, but I don't know of any that do. That automatically creates compatibility problems, which is unfortunate.

Comment: If you *need* a simple array of Unicode code-points, you can always use `uint32_t*`.  But then, all you can do is store them; there are no standard library functions to operate on UTF-32 strings (in C++98).

The bigger problem for cross-platform programs is interaction with the OS API.  Linux prefers using UTF-8, but Windows lacks native support for UTF-8 and thus you *have* to convert everything to UTF-16 and call the "W" API functions in order to properly support Unicode in filenames, etc.

Comment: I need just to cast it back to wide char on Linux. Just a single char per struct.

Comment: Starting from C++11: char16_t and char32_t exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing binary structures is inherently non portable. Bad things can happen almost everywhere :

- for any type larger than a `char` you can have endianess problem
- for any type shorter than 8 byte, you can have alignment problem - even if this can be mitigated with `#pragma`s on architectures and compilers that support it.

You should avoid that and instead use a kind of [marshalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29), that is serialization in a definite and architecture independant way. For example :

- `wchar_t charcode` - assuming that your charcode will never use more than 2 bytes, you explicitely convert it to a `char[2]` (in fact I'm forcing a 2 bytes big endian representation):

  ```
  code[0] = (charcode >> 8) & 0xFF;
  code[1] = charcode & 0xFF;
  ```
- `int` - **you** know whether you need 2, 4 or 8 bytes to represent any value for `width` and  `height` ; assuming it is 4 (`int32_t` or `uint32_t`)

  ```
  code[0] = (width >> 24) & 0xFF;
  code[1] = (width >> 16) & 0xFF;
  code[2] = (width >> 8) & 0xFF;
  code[3] = width & 0xFF;
  ```

So you explicitely define a conversion of your `struct DataBlock` in a `char` array with a definite size. Now you do have something portable over any network, architecture or compiler. Of course, you have do explicitely write the 2 routine for encoding and decoding, but it is the only way I know to have *portable binary structures*.

Hopefully, the `htonx` functions that can help you. They take explicitely 16 or 32 bits integers and force a conversion in *network* (big endian) order. From Linux man page :

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong);
uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort);
uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t netlong);
uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t netshort);
```

*The htonl() function converts the unsigned integer hostlong from host byte order to network byte order.*

*The htons() function converts the unsigned short integer hostshort from host byte order to network byte order.*

*The ntohl() function converts the unsigned integer netlong from network byte order to host byte order.*

*The ntohs() function converts the unsigned short integer netshort from network byte order to host byte order.*

That way, you directly write the fields of your struct :

```
long l = htonl(data.charcode); // or htons if you only need 16 bits
fwrite(&l, sizeof(long), 1, fdout); // sizeof(short) if you used 16 bits
```

and same for reading :

```
long l;
fread(&l, sizeof(long), 1, fdin);
data.charcode = ntohl(l);
```

This functions have been defined for a long time under Unix-like systems, and seem to be defined on recent versions of Windows compilers.

Of course, if you are absolutely sure that you will only use little endian architectures, you could even not convert for endianess. But be sure to right that in your documentation preferently in a red flashing font ...

Comment: My wide char can also take 3 bytes for some languages. Why not just use int and ten cast it to wide char at decoding. Bitwise operations are nice but my struct is much bigger than the example and has nested structures inside. I don't want to complicate.

Comment: `int` is not portable. It can be `int32_t` or `int64_t` depending on systems (and used to be 16 bits on older ones ...). And on Windows, a `wchar_t` will never be larger than 16 bits. But please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) full character set requires currently 32 bits to represent all possible values:

- The UTF-32 encoding stores these characters in 4 bytes, aka one `uint32_t`.
- The [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoding store each unicode character into one or two `uint16_t`
- The [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding stores each unicode character into one to four `uint8_t`

Typically, [windows uses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `wchar_t` to store unicode text in **UTF-16** encoding.  At the time this was decided, UTF-16 was able to hold all the unicode caracter set, which is [no longer true today](http://utf8everywhere.org/).  Linux uses an UTF-8 encoding.  Most implementations use `char` to store unicode text in UTF-8.

The standard gives you some tools to cope with **encoding conversions**:

- You can use the **[`wbuffer_convert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/wbuffer_convert/)** together with **[`codecvt`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/codecvt/?kw=codecvt)** faced to convert between `wchar_t` UTF16 and UTF8 encoding when reading/writing streams.
- You can also use **[`wstring_convert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/wstring_convert/)** to convert strings that are aloready loaded in memory between UTF16 and UTF8.

If you just want to use a cross system data structure in a binary file and without making conversions, just use:

```
struct DataBlock{
    uint16_t charcode;   // if you assing in windows from a wchar_t, no problem
    ...
}
```

Comment: Codecvt is unimplemented on GCC 4.7 which I currently use on Linux. Also, as I already said, all I need is to encode chars which can potentially be wider than 1 byte on win and read them into wchar t on Linux. In my struct, as I see it, the issue is that when writing binary the  char variable is 2 bytes while on Linux it's 4 .

Comment: Ok.  If you need to read the file on linux and windows, and if it's a binary file, then you have to use a struct which has the same binary layout on both sides (see edit).

Comment: But if I assign on Linux to wchar_t which is 4 bytes will that be a problem?

Comment: If under linux you assign an uint16_t to a larger wchar_t (should however be assessed in code using limits) std integer promotion rules ensure that it'll be fine. But std doesn't ensure that int16_t is stored in a uniform way: different cpu architectures might use different "endian"-ness. This is why it's so difficult to write binary compatible files in a portable manner.

Comment: All my target  CPUs are Intel,so I am ok in this respect :)